# Проблемы с подгрузкой DLL из DLL

Tags: c++, winapi, dll

Здравствуйте. Такой вопрос: есть **`ехе`** , есть **`dll №1`** и есть **`dll №2`**.В **`ехе`** загружаю обе библиотеки (с помощью `LoadLibrary`,ф-ии экспортируются через `extern "C" _declspec(dllexport)`), при этом в `Main функции` первой библиотеки также подгружается библиотека №2. То есть, **`dll №2`** подгружается дважды, я правильно понимаю?

Моя проблема заключается в том, что **`dll №1`** подгрузила **`dll №2`**, и вроде, как получила адрес экспортируемой, из **`dll №2`** функции(`GetProcAddress` не вернула 0). Но функцию вызвать не удаётся - крах программы.(с **`exe`**-шника функция запускается нормально)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Хм, здесь пахнет `undefined behaviour`'ом или неправильным распознаванием истинной проблемы. Вообще, если в памяти уже присутствует библиотека(а менеджер памяти Windows ведет свой низкоуровневый лог загруженных в адресное пространство модулей), то повторная её загрузка в то же самое виртуальное пространство не должна производиться(хотя зависит от версии Windows и имплементации LoadLibrary) - должен просто возвратиться адрес уже импортированной библиотеки.

Используемый вами подход скорее всего неправильный, но дабы не погружаться в ваши дебри, можно посоветовать следующее:

1. Проверяйте наличие в памяти нужной библиотеки, прежде чем слепо вызывать LoadLibrary, где бы то ни было.
2. Используйте **[LoadLibraryEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms684179(v=vs.85).aspx)** для более безопасной загрузки DLL`ок

Для отладки советую вам сравнить адреса любой одной и той же импортируемой функций до и после попытки повторного импорта второй либы(aka после вызова её DllMain, aka после исполнения LoadLibrary внутри 1 либы), дабы точно убедиться в том, что не происходит обновление таблицы адресов функций, и повторная попытка загрузки библиотеки не влияет на состояние памяти.

Comment: Я нашёл проблему. В первой `dll` нужно было после получения адреса функции вызвать `FreeLibrary` , потом уже вызывать функцию. Не знаю как это помогло, но помогло..

Comment: За ответ спасибо, буду пользоваться `LoadLibraryEx`

Comment: @Алесандр Вогрик, советую вам быть предельно осторожным и использовать рутину по загрузке-выгрузке dll в пределах одного и того же модуля, т.е освобождать ресурсы там, где вы их захватили. Иначе же будет много проблем.

Comment: понял, буду переосмысливать свой  код. Спасибо!